# Time not getting selected with the single click in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input boxes one is for selecting date and another for time, I am trying to validate these two boxes based on some conditions, such that if the date is not selected, the time should not get selected and i'm using eonasdan datetimepicker, i'm getting the desired output but not with the single click on a timepicker can some one help me out with this Thank you

Here's what i have done so far :

```js
function starttime(){
            $('#starttime').datetimepicker({
                  format: 'HH:mm',
                  minDate: new Date()
                });
           }
           
           $('.start_time_addon').on('click keyup',function(){
            var x = $('#start').val();
           if (x == '') {

            alert('please select startdate first');
            return false;
           
           }
           else{

            starttime();
            
           }
          
        });
        
        var datePickerSix= $('.datetimepicker6');
          $(datePickerSix).datetimepicker({
          format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
          
minDate: new Date()
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Start Date</label><br>
             <div class='input-group date datetimepicker6'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="start" name="date_end"
                                           placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"/>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                            </span>
                                </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
                   <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="start_time" class="col-form-label">Start Time</label>
                <div class='input-group date start_time_addon' id='starttime'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="HH : MM" id="Start_Time" required />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
        
                          </div>
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('.datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
          format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
          
minDate: new Date()

        });
       $('.datetimepicker6').on("dp.change", function(e) {
            $('#starttime').datetimepicker({
            
                  format: 'HH:mm',
                  minDate: new Date()
                });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Start Date</label><br>
             <div class='input-group date datetimepicker6'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control input_date" id="start" name="date_end"
                                           placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"/>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                            </span>
                                </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
                   <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="start_time" class="col-form-label">Start Time</label>
                <div class='input-group date start_time_addon' id='starttime'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="HH : MM" id="Start_Time" required />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
        
                          </div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: @Adrian Ghiuta,thanks for the edit, this is working fine, but whenever we are trying to  enter manually in input field it is accepting the values, rather it should update input field with the current date and time, can you help me out with this? Thank you in advance